# Got a very strange syntax error in java

Tags: java, syntax

I got a very strange error in my java program.
This code shows no error:

```
buttonPlay.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                /*public GameScreen(Create create) {
                    this.create = create;
                }*/
            }
        });
```

But if I remove the comments, `Eclipse` states that there are two errors:

1. I should insert a "}" to complete the method body of "public void
   clicked".
2. I should delete the last "}" of the code.

So the "`public GameScreen(Create create)`" creates the problem, that `Eclipse` suddenly no more knows where the block starts and end (I think).

I have really no explanation for this and would be glad for every answer.

Comment: can you share the code after removing the commented area please?

Comment: You are trying to declare a constructor within a method body. Where's the surprise, exactly?

Comment: Yeah, I facepalmed myself very hard, so I'll never try to do this again, hopefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the commented-out code uncommented, you're trying to declare a constructor directly within a method. You can't do that in Java.

```
// You can't do this
buttonPlay.addListener(new ClickListener(){                   // 1
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) { // 2
        public GameScreen(Create create) {                    // 3
            this.create = create;                             // 3
        }                                                     // 3
    }
});
```

1. Instantiating an anonymous class. This is fine.
2. Implementing a method of that anonymous class (you want to add an `@Override` there). Also fine.
3. Declaring a constructor directly within another method. You can't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, helped a lot :).

Answer (score 1):

`public void clicked(...)` is a method and within it, you're trying to create a constructor (at least that's the content of the commented code).

Constructors are class-specific *blocks* and cannot be nested within methods. That's why the compilation fails.